# Matching columns in data set with its class, similar to VLOOKUP

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, merge, melt

I have a large data set which the head of it looks like this:

```
          Time  Company 1  Company 2  ...  Company 12  Company 13  Company 14
0    1/01/2015         49         19  ...          80          56          61
1    2/01/2015          2         92  ...          28          98          72
2    3/01/2015         39         69  ...          93          10          66
3    4/01/2015         31         54  ...          78           9          84
4    5/01/2015         37         81  ...          59          32          99
5    6/01/2015         83         69  ...          67          12          69
6    7/01/2015         38          7  ...          37          50          22
7    8/01/2015         75         90  ...          29          99          90
8    9/01/2015          2          7  ...           4          84          59
9   10/01/2015         14         66  ...          40          51          78
10  11/01/2015         20         87  ...           7          26          52
11  12/01/2015         33         84  ...          80          81          69
12  13/01/2015         93         90  ...           4          55          65
13  14/01/2015         95         47  ...          16          43          75
14  15/01/2015         71         66  ...          53          36           0
15  16/01/2015         98         26  ...          41          48          31
16  17/01/2015         29         29  ...           3          13           9
17  18/01/2015         46         96  ...          99          52          71
18  19/01/2015         27         91  ...          50          65          21
19  20/01/2015         45         64  ...          24          97          87

[20 rows x 15 columns]
```

This is in a csv file, I then have a separate csv file that says which `company` is in which `class`, like so:

```
     Company1  B
0    Company2  B
1    Company3  C
2    Company4  A
3    Company5  A
4    Company6  A
5    Company7  C
6    Company8  B
7    Company9  A
8   Company10  A
9   Company11  B
10  Company12  C
11  Company13  A
12  Company14  C
```

I want to get rid of the columns `company1,...,company14` and instead just have the columns `A,B,C`. I know how to do this in excel with a simple `VLOOKUP` function, however my data set is very large and thus using `VLOOKUP` in excel is not viable.

Is there any way I can achieve my desired result using python?

Here is what my desired output looks like:

```
          Time    A    B    C
0    1/01/2015  283  228  230
1    2/01/2015  303  158  224
2    3/01/2015  243  163  277
3    4/01/2015  306  259  250
4    5/01/2015  257  232  242
5    6/01/2015  258  160  288
6    7/01/2015  406  136  170
7    8/01/2015  407  180  239
8    9/01/2015  283   98  127
9   10/01/2015  321  144  248
10  11/01/2015  344  296  212
11  12/01/2015  372  175  243
12  13/01/2015  133  249  181
13  14/01/2015  251  245  214
14  15/01/2015  227  263  226
15  16/01/2015  344  154  180
16  17/01/2015  361  146  124
17  18/01/2015  337  290  245
18  19/01/2015  252  247  212
19  20/01/2015  315  169  219
```

EDIT1:

```
       Company1  B
0      Company2  B
1      Company3  C
2      Company4  A
3      Company5  A
4      Company6  A
5      Company7  C
6      Company8  B
7      Company9  A
8     Company10  A
9     Company11  B
10    Company12  C
11    Company13  A
12    Company14  C
13    Company15  B
14    Company16  B
15    Company17  C
16    Company18  A
17    Company19  A
18    Company20  A
19    Company21  C
20    Company22  B
21    Company23  A
22    Company24  A
23    Company25  B
24    Company26  C
25    Company27  A
26    Company28  C
27    Company29  B
28    Company30  B
29    Company31  C
..          ... ..
301  Company303  A
302  Company304  A
303  Company305  B
304  Company306  C
305  Company307  A
306  Company308  C
307  Company309  B
308  Company310  B
309  Company311  C
310  Company312  A
311  Company313  A
312  Company314  A
313  Company315  C
314  Company316  B
315  Company317  A
316  Company318  A
317  Company319  B
318  Company320  C
319  Company321  A
320  Company322  C
321  Company323  B
322  Company324  B
323  Company325  C
324  Company326  A
325  Company327  A
326  Company328  A
327  Company329  C
328  Company330  B
329  Company331  A
330  Company332  A

[331 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Sorry, what are the numbers `283  228  230` represent in the result data frame you have in the first row?

Comment: They are the sum of all the data in `A,B,C` respectively. E.g. `230 = company 3 + company 7 + company 12`

Comment: I think I got it. Please check whether I've understood the workflow correctly in the answer I gave.

Comment: Great, I'll have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do four distinct operations to get to your desired state. It looks like you are using pandas, so I'll outline a solution using pandas.

1. **melt** the large dataframe. This lets you turn columns into rows in a similar way that you could use a pivot table in excel.

[Pandas Melt Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34830597/pandas-melt-function)

2. **merge** the large dataframe (make this the left) with the small dataframe (make this the right). This is a more powerful version of a vlookup. You want to use a **left join** that is on both **time** and **class**.

[Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

3. **aggregate** the result from your merge and group by **time**. I assume you want to sum, but you can do many other aggregate functions like count, min, max. Check the pandas documentation for more details.

[Pandas group-by and sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/pandas-group-by-and-sum)

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html

4. **pivot** the data into your desired result shape. A pivot is the opposite of **melt**. With the melt we transposed columns into rows. With a **pivot**, we are turning rows into columns,

[How to pivot a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Here's a code snippet that is written in logical steps, not for optimal performance. The hope is that you can walk through each step for better understanding. Note that I put headers in the csv files, so you may need to declare column names in your dataframe depending on how you are importing the data.

**largeCsv Headers:**   Time,Company1,Company2,Company3,Company4,Company5

**smallCsv Headers:**   name, class

```
import pandas as pd

dfSmall = pd.read_csv('c:/temp/smallCsv.csv')

dfLarge = pd.read_csv('c:/temp/largeCsv.csv')

dfMeltedLarge = pd.melt(dfLarge, id_vars=['Time'], var_name='name')

dfMerged = dfMeltedLarge.merge(dfSmall, on='name', how='left')[['Time', 'class', 'value']]

dfSum = dfMerged.groupby(['Time', 'class']).sum()

dfResult = dfSum.pivot_table(index='Time', columns='class', values='value')
```

Comment: Ok great I'll give it a go

Comment: In step two when I merge, I get `KeyError: 'Time'` I think this is because there is no time column in the class data, is this right?

Comment: This is what I did for step1: `import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
data = pd.melt(data, id_vars=['Time'])`

Comment: Sorry, I thought I saw time in the small dataframe. Give me a few minutes and I'll post code. ;)

Comment: Thanks! What headers did you put in the csv file?

Comment: As long as your big file headers EXACTLY match the name column in that small file you will be fine. If they don't match, then the merge will break.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the reproducible dataset you can run the code with.

The code:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.max_columns = 10

headers = [
    'Time',
    'Company1',
    'Company2',
    'Company3',
    'Company4',
    'Company5',
    'Company6',
]
records = [
    ('1/01/2015', 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60),
    ('2/01/2015', 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600),
    ('3/01/2015', 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000),
]

data = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records, columns=headers)

mapper = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ('Company1', 'A'),
        ('Company2', 'A'),
        ('Company3', 'B'),
        ('Company4', 'B'),
        ('Company5', 'C'),
        ('Company6', 'C'),
    ],
    columns=['Company', 'Class'],
)
for col_name in ['A', 'B', 'C']:
    class_companies_group = mapper[mapper['Class'] == col_name]['Company'].values
    data[col_name] = data[class_companies_group].sum(axis=1)

result = data[['Time', 'A', 'B', 'C']]
print(result)
```

The output result:

```
        Time     A     B      C
0  1/01/2015    30    70    110
1  2/01/2015   300   700   1100
2  3/01/2015  3000  7000  11000
```