# How can I tidy (melt) data in Pandas and keep all other columns?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider this Pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'User ID': [1, 2, 2, 3],
    'Cupcakes': [1, 5, 4, 2],
    'Biscuits': [2, 5, 3, 3],
    'Score': [0.65, 0.12, 0.15, 0.9]
})
```

ie.

```
   User ID  Cupcakes  Biscuits  Score
0        1         1         2   0.65
1        2         5         5   0.12
2        2         4         3   0.15
3        3         2         3   0.90
```

I want to [tidy ("melt")](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) this data so that the dessert *type* are separate observations. But I also want to keep the score for each user.

Using [`melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) directly doesn't work:

```
df.melt(
    id_vars=['User ID'],
    value_vars=['Cupcakes', 'Biscuits'],
    var_name='Dessert', value_name='Enjoyment'
)
```

...gives:

```
   User ID   Dessert  Enjoyment
0        1  Cupcakes          1
1        2  Cupcakes          5
2        2  Cupcakes          4
3        3  Cupcakes          2
4        1  Biscuits          2
5        2  Biscuits          5
6        2  Biscuits          3
7        3  Biscuits          3
```

I've lost the score data!

I can't use [`wide_to_long()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html?highlight=wide_to_long#pandas.wide_to_long) because I don't have a common "stub name" for my dessert types.

I can't join or merge the tidied data with the original data because the tidied data is reindexed and the user ID is not unique for each observation.

How do I tidy this data but retain columns that aren't involved in the tidying?

Comment: I should add to this that upon further reading of that "tidy data" paper, it seems like the *truly* correct approach is to separate the score data into another table, with a new shared index (eg. "observation number") between the two tables.

Answer (score 12):

Add column `Score` to `id_vars` in [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

> **id_vars** : tuple, list, or ndarray, optional
>
> Column(s) to use as identifier variables.

```
df1 = df.melt(
    id_vars=['User ID', 'Score'],
    value_vars=['Cupcakes', 'Biscuits'],
    var_name='Dessert', value_name='Enjoyment'
)
print (df1)
   User ID  Score   Dessert  Enjoyment
0        1   0.65  Cupcakes          1
1        2   0.12  Cupcakes          5
2        2   0.15  Cupcakes          4
3        3   0.90  Cupcakes          2
4        1   0.65  Biscuits          2
5        2   0.12  Biscuits          5
6        2   0.15  Biscuits          3
7        3   0.90  Biscuits          3
```

If need melting all columns without `User ID` and `Score` omit `value_vars`:

```
df.melt(
    id_vars=['User ID', 'Score'],
    var_name='Dessert', value_name='Enjoyment'
)
```

Comment: Huh, I missed that `id_vars` took a list. I had assumed from the name that `id_vars` should be an index-like column (ie. not a "dependent" variable), but it doesn't have to be, does it?

Comment: @detly - If check docs -  [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) - `Column(s) to use as identifier variables.`

Comment: Oh I read it, I just didn't know what was strictly meant by "identifier variables."

Comment: @detly - hmmm, not sure about definition, but one or more columns are identifier variables (id_vars), while all other columns, considered measured variables (value_vars), are “unpivoted” to the row axis, leaving just two non-identifier columns, ‘variable’ and ‘value’. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34830597/pandas-melt-function)