# Dataframe: How to transpose/merge sparse columns as rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe as below.

```
data = {'Year':["2012", "2013", "2014", "2015","2016"], 
       'Matthew':[80,83,85,90,91], 
       'Aakash':[85,75,95,92,93], 
       'Jill': [90,70,100,80,85]} 
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
   Year  Matthew  Aakash  Jill
0  2012       80      85    90
1  2013       83      75    70
2  2014       85      95   100
3  2015       90      92    80
4  2016       91      93    85
```

How do I transform it to below?

**Expected Result:**

```
data2 = {'Year':["2012","2012","2012", "2013","2013","2013","2014","2014","2014","2015","2015","2015","2016","2016","2016"], 
        'Name':['Matthew','Aakash','Jill','Matthew','Aakash','Jill','Matthew','Aakash','Jill','Matthew','Aakash','Jill','Matthew','Aakash','Jill'],
        'Results':[80,85,90,83,75,70,85,95,100,90,92,80,91,93,85]
        }  

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

```
    Year     Name  Results
0   2012  Matthew       80
1   2012   Aakash       85
2   2012     Jill       90
3   2013  Matthew       83
4   2013   Aakash       75
5   2013     Jill       70
6   2014  Matthew       85
7   2014   Aakash       95
8   2014     Jill      100
9   2015  Matthew       90
10  2015   Aakash       92
11  2015     Jill       80
12  2016  Matthew       91
13  2016   Aakash       93
14  2016     Jill       85
```

Comment: Could you provide some code you may have tried to write already?

Comment: `df.melt(id_vars=['Year'], var_name='Name', value_name='Results').sort_values('Year')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Melt Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34830597/pandas-melt-function)

Comment: Yes - that solved my issue. Thanks.